# Proof of inequality$\Vert f_1S_1^*+f_2 S_2^*\Vert^2\geq\Vert f_1\Vert^2+\Vert f_2\Vert^2$ for functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, modules

I was trying to prove Remark 3.7 in [this article](http://www.mrlonline.org/jot/2011-065-001/2011-065-001-005.pdf), but failed. Here some necessary definitions.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra such that there exist $S_1,S_2\in\mathcal{A}$ with property $S_1^*S_1=S_2^*S_2=1_{\mathcal{A}}$, $S_1^*S_2=S_2^*S_1=0$ (i.e. isometries with pairwise orthogonal images)

Let $Y$ be contractive (i.e. for all $a\in\mathcal{A}$, $y\in Y$ we have $\Vert a\cdot y\Vert\leq\Vert a\Vert\Vert y\Vert$) normed (i.e. normed space) unital (i.e. for all $y\in Y$ we have $1_\mathcal{A}y=y$) left module over $\mathcal{A}$.

Such a normed module is called semi-Ruan if for all $y_1, y_2\in Y$ the following holds
$$
\Vert S_1\cdot y_1+S_2\cdot y_2\Vert^2\leq\Vert y_1\Vert^2+\Vert y_2\Vert^2
$$

**My question.** 
Let $Y^*$ be dual module of semi-Ruan module $Y$ (i.e. dual space with the structure of right unital contractive normed module with outer multiplication defined by $(f\cdot a)(y)=f(a\cdot y)$ ), then the following inequality holds
$$
\Vert f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*\Vert^2\geq\Vert f_1\Vert^2+\Vert f_2\Vert^2
$$
**My attempt.** 
Note that $\Vert y_1\Vert\leq 1$,$\Vert y_2\Vert\leq 1$ implies $\Vert S_1\cdot y_1+S_2\cdot y_2\Vert\leq\sqrt{2}$, so
$$
\Vert f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*\Vert^2=\sup\{|(f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*)(y)|^2:\Vert y\Vert\leq 1\}\geq
$$
$$
\sup\left\{\left|(f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*)\left(S_1\cdot\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{2}}+S_2\cdot\frac{y_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|^2:\Vert y_1\Vert\leq 1,\Vert y_2\Vert\leq 1\right\}=
$$
$$
0.5 \sup\left\{|f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2:\Vert y_1\Vert\leq 1,\Vert y_2\Vert\leq 1\right\}=
$$
$$
0.5 \sup\left\{|f_1(y_1)|^2+|f_2(y_2)|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(f_1(y_1)\overline{f_2(y_2)}):\Vert y_1\Vert\leq 1,\Vert y_2\Vert\leq 1\right\}=???
$$

Comment: Are you also assuming that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are isometries? If so, you should probably add that to the question.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't read carefully enough. My apologies.

Comment: Hint: Your final supremum is equal to $0.5( \|f_1\| + \|f_2\|)^2$.  Actually, it's easiest to see this from the line before.  This isn't what you want, but suppose instead you had taken the supremum over all $y_1,y_2$ with $\|y_1\|^2 + \|y_2\|^2\leq 1$...

Comment: So you propose the following $$\Vert f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*\Vert^2=$$$$\sup\{|(f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*)(y)|^2:\Vert y\Vert\leq 1\}\geq$$ $$\sup\left\{\left|(f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*)\left(S_1\cdot y_1+S_2\cdot y_2\right)\right|^2:\Vert y_1\Vert^2+\Vert y_2\Vert^2\leq 1\right\}=$$$$\sup\left\{|f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2:\Vert y_1\Vert^2+\Vert y_2\Vert^2\leq 1\right\}$$ But, why the last supremum equals to $\Vert f_1\Vert^2+\Vert f_2\Vert^2$? This supremum is taken over dependent variables.

Comment: @MatthewDaws I was thinking about your hint but haven't come to any conclusions. Do you know a complete solution, or that hint was just an idea that you think may be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe a comment, but it became too long.  We seem to agree that
$$ \|f_1\cdot S_1^*+f_2\cdot S_2^*\|^2 \geq \sup\big\{ |f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2 : \|y_1\|^2+\|y_2\|^2\leq 1 \big\}. $$
Now, if $a_1,a_2\geq 0$ are such that $a_1^2+a_2^2\leq 1$ then for each $\epsilon>0$, we can pick $z_k$ with $|f_k(z_k)| = f_k(z_k) > \|f_k\|-\epsilon$, and with $\|z_k\|=1$.  So setting $y_k = a_kz_k$, we see that
$$ \sup\big\{ |f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2 : \|y_1\|^2+\|y_2\|^2\leq 1 \big\} \geq
\sup\big\{ (a_1\|f_1\|+a_2\|f_2\|)^2 : a_1^2+a_2^2\leq 1 \big\}. $$
But this supremum involves only scalars, and it's standard (I guess via Cauchy-Schwarz-- think about the proof that $(\ell^2)^*=\ell^2$) that this equals
$$ \|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2. $$
Conversely, $|f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2 \leq ( \|f_1\|\|y_1\| + \|f_2\|\|y_2\| )^2
\leq (\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2)(\|y_1\|^2+\|y_2\|^2)$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.  So actually
$$ \sup\big\{ |f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)|^2 : \|y_1\|^2+\|y_2\|^2\leq 1 \big\}
= \|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2. $$
And we're done!

Comment: Ah, the old proof that the p-norm is a sup over pairing with things in the ball of the q-norm. (Flashbacks to a certain AJW course, perhaps?)

Comment: @Norbert, erm, yes, I guess.  But the result is true for more than two summands, which would be less clear from your proof.  Actually, all I was proving I guess is that the dual of the vector-valued space $\ell^2(F)$ is $\ell^2(F^*)$ for the obvious dual pairing...